# How to elevate a gas water heater about 1" above the floor drain

Tags: water-heater

I recently had a new gas water heater installed in our laundry room. It was several inches wider than the old one. As a result, the installer sat it on top of the floor drain, completely covering it. He assured me it was ok. I disagree. What can I safely put under it to raise it about an inch to uncover the drain? Thanks

Comment: Usually use thin cement blocks/pads, but does the water pipes and gas line have enough give or will they need to be added to or have to be shorten.